# How to filter multi react-select data against json array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

I have 2 json files 1 has a list of symptoms, the second file has a list of conditions with a json array of symptoms that match the condition. I am trying to find a way to use react-select to search the array of symptoms in the conditions json table and get only those that match. As I add more symptoms from the react select, fewer and fewer conditions should show up. I have tried many things I am just having no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// condition_symptoms.js
export const condition_symptoms = [
 {
    condition: "Acetaminophen And Nsaid Toxicity",
    symptions: ["Arm Pain", "Back Pain"],
  },
  {
    condition: "Acne",
    symptions: ["Leg Pain", "Back Pian", "Face Pain", "Arm Pain"],
  },
  {
    condition: "Adrenal Disorders (Addison’S Disease And Cushing’S Syndrome",
    symptions: ["Foot Pain", "Leg Pain", "Arm Pain"],
  },
  {
    condition: "Age Related Cognitive Decline",
    symptions: ["Jaw Pain", "Foot Pain", "Leg Pain", "Mouth Pain"],
  },
export default condition_symptoms ;

// symptoms.js
export const symptoms = [
  { value: "leg pain", label: "Leg Pain" },
  { value: "arm Pain", label: "Arm Pain" },
  { value: "foot pain", label: "Foot Pain" },
  { value: "back pain", label: "Back Pain" },
]

// component.js
import symptomsConditions from "conditions_symptoms";
import symptoms from "symptoms";

function LandingPage() {

const onChange = (newValue) => {

    console.log("onChange", newValue);
    const condition = symptomsConditions.filter(symptom => {
      symptom = Filter out condition here
    } )
  };

return {
              <Select
              onChange={onChange}
              noOptionsMessage={() => "Please select a valid Symptom"}
              placeholder="Please select symptoms"
              options={symptoms}
              size="large"
              isMulti
              isSearchable
            />
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but something like this may do the trick;

Basically the `filter` and `includes` functions should give you a starting point.

```
var symptomsFound = symptoms.filter(function (s1) {
return !condition_symptoms.some(function (cs1) {
    return cs1.symptions.includes(s1.value);
   });
});
```